# Drool Rule with sliding window example

Tags: drools

I am a newbie to Drools and am trying to use sliding window in drool for few sensor data. The  doc which I am following is  https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.47.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#cep-sliding-windows-con_decision-engine

Here is my POJO class:

```
package com.ruletemplate;

public class RuleTemplate {
private String DeviceName;
private String ParameterName;
private int ParameterValue;
private String AlertMessage; 

public RuleTemplate( String parametername )
{
    this.ParameterName = parametername;
}

public String getParameterName() {
    return ParameterName;
}
public void setPropertyName(String parametername) {
    this.ParameterName = parametername;
}

public int  getParameterValue() {
    return ParameterValue;
}
public void setParameterValue(int parametervalue) {
    this.ParameterValue = parametervalue;
}

public String getDeviceName() {
    return DeviceName;
}

public void setDeviceName(String devicename) {
    this.DeviceName = devicename;
}

public String getAlertMessage() {
    return AlertMessage;
}

public void setAlertMessage(String alertmessage) {
    this.AlertMessage = alertmessage;
}    
}
```

The drool engine runs on Azure Databricks runtime version 7.0 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)

The drool rule is defined as:

```
import com.ruletemplate.RuleTemplate
rule 'Rule_Pump_Controller_Test_Device_12'
agenda-group 'Pump_Controller_Test_Device'
when
ruletemplate: RuleTemplate(ParameterName=='Voltage', ParameterValue > 0, ParameterValue < 
40)  over window:time(1m)
then
ruletemplate.setAlertMessage(ruletemplate.getDeviceName()+ ','+ 
ruletemplate.getParameterName() +', '+ruletemplate.getParameterValue()+ 
',3,Nodename,ActionsName');
end
```

The way the rule is fired is:

```
val ruletemplate=new RuleTemplate(TelemetryName)
ruletemplate.setParameterValue(TelemetryValue.toInt)
ruletemplate.setDeviceName(Deviceid)
session.insert(ruletemplate) 
agenda.getAgendaGroup(Deviceid).setFocus();              
session.fireAllRules()
```

This works perfectly without the sliding time window added.Once sliding window is added the rule gets evaluated but returns null .Looking for some help for examples or document on how we can define sliding window with accumulate for finite length of time and for the ones define above(without accumulate).

Comment: You've configured your application to run Drools in stream mode rather than the default cloud mode, correct?

Comment: Yes, its in stream mode.

Comment: But what is this window supposed to do? Conceptually it doesn't make any sense. If you use it on an `accumulate`, for example, then it means "if we accumulate sufficient events that meet these conditions over this window of time", but it doesn't really make sense for "single event over period of time".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.The idea was to use accumulate to an event for a window (say Voltage > 3V for a window of last 10 minutes) then fire an action. I agree for single window it may not be a valid case but for accumulate it would be perfect.

Comment: OK, so basically you're taking readings and you want the rule to fire if the voltage gets above 3V and stays there for 10 minutes? That's do-able, though I would personally use the temporal operators instead of a sliding window for that. Is the sliding window a hard-requirement?

Comment: Yes , in a sliding window of 15 minutes say avg(voltage) is > 3 V then execute an action that would enable some kind of charge protection.

Comment: You can do that with temporal operators; I want to know if it must be a sliding window instead.

Comment: Could you please share any example on how we can achieve it with temporal operators .The current rule is:

import com.ruletemplate.RuleTemplate
rule 'Rule_Pump_Controller_Test_Device_12'
agenda-group 'Pump_Controller_Test_Device'
when
Number(doubleValue > 10.0) from accumulate(  ruletemplate: RuleTemplate(ParameterName=='Voltage',$param:ParameterValue)   over window:time( 1m ),average($param))
then
ruletemplate.setAlertMessage(ruletemplate.getDeviceName()+ ','+ 
ruletemplate.getParameterName() +', '+ruletemplate.getParameterValue()+ 
',3,Nodename,ActionsName');
end

Comment: It accumulates  Voltage reading from Sensor for a minute and if the average for that window is greater than 10 then take an action.
But I haven't still managed to get it working.